# How does one convert an integrand of the form $\frac{x\sinh x-t\sinh t}{\sinh^2x-\sinh^2t}$ into the form $\frac{\ln(x^2-t^2+1)}{\sinh^2x-\sinh^2t}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, contour-integration, gamma-function, hyperbolic-functions

$\newcommand{\pv}{\mathrm{P.V.}}\newcommand{\Log}{\mathrm{Log}}\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$This is exercise 4 from a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257381156_Rediscovery_of_Malmsten%27s_integrals_their_evaluation_by_contour_integration_methods_and_some_related_results) - pages 53, 54 - about the contour integration of Malmsten's integrals and related logarithmic forms.

I successfully completed exercise $6$ $a$ through $c$, but am stuck on the applications of these results. I shown that, where $a,t$ are positive reals:

$$\begin{align}\pv\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}{\sinh x\pm\sinh t}\d x &= \pm\frac{1}{\cosh t} \left\{4t\ln2\pi+\pi^2-2\pi\arctan\frac{a}{t} \vphantom{\frac12}\right.\\ 
&\left. {} + 4\pi\cdot\Im\left[\Log\Gamma\left(\frac{a+it}{2\pi}\right)-\Log\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a-it}{2\pi}\right)\right]\right\}
\end{align}$$

With the corollaries (for $0\lt t\le1$):

$$\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2-t^2+1)}{\sinh x\pm\sinh t}\d x \\
& \hspace{30pt} = \pm\frac{1}{\cosh t}\left\{4t\ln2\pi+\pi^2-2\pi\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}\right. \\
& \hspace{90pt}\left.{} + 4\pi\cdot\Im\biggl[\Log\Gamma\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}+it}{2\pi}\
\Bigr)-\Log\Gamma\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}-it}{2\pi}\Bigr)\biggr]\right\} \\
&\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2-t^2+1)}{\sinh^2t-\sinh^2x}\d x \\
& \hspace{30pt} =\frac{1}{\sinh2t} \left\{4t\ln2\pi+\pi^2-2\pi\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t} \right.\\
& \hspace{90pt}\left.{} + 4\pi\cdot\Im\biggl[\Log\Gamma\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}+it}{2\pi}\Bigr)-\Log\Gamma\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}-it}{2\pi}\Bigr)\biggr]\right\}
\end{align}$$

The author, without only the hint that these may be found "with the help of the last formula", leaves the following integrals to be evaluated:

$$\begin{align}\tag{1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x+t}{\sinh x+\sinh t}\d x&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{x\sinh x-t\sinh t}{\sinh^2x-\sinh^2t}\d x=\frac{\pi^2+4t^2}{2\cosh t}\\\tag{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2-t^2}{\sinh x+\sinh t}\d x&=-\frac{t(\pi^2+4t^2)}{3\cosh t}\end{align}$$

Etc.

I have spent hours staring at these now. I was able to show the above integral formulae but I don't have a clue how to apply them to these integrals. It is strongly unclear to me how to convert the numerator of the form $x\sinh x-t\sinh t$ into one of the form $\ln(x^2-t^2+1)$. Common themes in this paper have been taking limits as the constant $a$ goes to zero, and substitutions of the form $x\mapsto e^x$ to convert hyperbolics into polynomials, and indeed even taking principal values and then applying them to convergent integrals; I've thought about all of this, and just cannot see the link. I considered contour integration; the problem is, which contour, and what integrand? If these could be evaluated by plain and simple contour integration, they wouldn't be in this paper! Those integrals are supposed to be related *somehow* to the three formulae at the top, especially the third one, and the provided answers are similar in spirit to the formulae, but many of the log terms, in particular the log gamma term, are missing. This suggests I find integrals $(1)$ and $(2)$ by taking the difference of two integrals with numerator of the form $\ln(x^2-t^2+1)$, but they are different enough that I cannot see the connections.

I've been happy with my ability to do these exercises *so far*, so I'd really just like a constructive hint to get the ball rolling on this one.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I tried my best with the formatting, put small font on, but the formulae are simply too large for my limited MathJax skills to properly handle

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Your edits are good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

After looking at the paper more carefully, I think the author is referring to the formula for $$\operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-iax}}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx.$$ I think they want the reader to differentiate under the integral sign.

There's not much information available about about when DUTIS can be justified when the integral only exists as a Cauchy principal value integral.

---

The following approach is more direct and easier to justify.

Let's integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{z^{\color{red}{2}}}{\sinh z+ \sinh t}, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}, $$ around an indented rectangular contour $C_{R}$ with vertices at $z= \pm R, \pm R + 2 \pi i. $

There are simple poles on the contour at $z= -t$ and $z= -t + 2 \pi i$.  There is also a simple pole inside the contour at $z= t+ \pi i $.

Letting $R \to \infty$,  the integral vanishes on the vertical sides of the contour because the magnitude of  $\sinh z$ grows exponentially as $\Re(z) \to \pm \infty$.

Therefore,  we have $$ \begin{align} \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{C_{R}} f(z) \mathrm \, dz &=  \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx - \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2 \pi i)^{2}}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= -4 \pi i \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx + 4 \pi^{2} \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \pi i \operatorname{Res}[f(z), -t] + \pi i \operatorname{Res} [f(z), -t+ 2 \pi i] + 2 \pi i\operatorname{Res}[f(z), t + \pi i] \\ &= \frac{8 \pi^{2} t}{\cosh t} - i \, \frac{2 \pi^{3}}{\cosh t}. \end{align} $$

Equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, we get $$\operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi^{2}}{2\cosh t}. $$

And equating the real parts on both sides of the equation, we get $$\operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx =  \frac{2t}{\cosh t}. $$

Therefore, $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x+t}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi^{2} }{2\cosh t} +  \frac{2t^{2}}{\cosh t} = \frac{\pi^{2} + 4 t^{2}}{2 \cosh t}.$$

The Cauchy principal value sign was dropped because the integral converges in the traditional sense.

---

If we integrate $$g(z) = \frac{z^{3}}{\sinh z + \sinh t} $$ around the same contour and then equate the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, we find that $$-6 \pi \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx + 8 \pi^{3} \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{18\pi^{3}t - 4 \pi t^{3}}{\cosh t}. $$

Therefore, $$\operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx = - \frac{1}{6 \pi} \left(\frac{18\pi^{3}t - 4 \pi t^{3}}{\cosh t}- 8 \pi^{3} \frac{2t}{\cosh t} \right)= \frac{2t^{3} - \pi^{2}t}{3\cosh t}, $$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}-t^{2}}{\sinh x + \sinh t} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{2t^{3} - \pi^{2}t}{3\cosh t} - \frac{2t^{3}}{\cosh t} = -\frac{t \left(\pi^{2}+ 4 t^{2} \right)}{3\cosh t}.$$

Comment: Absolutely maddening that his formulas weren’t needed. I’d have been trying the wrong thing for ages without this!

Comment: @FShrike  The author may have been referring to a different formula. I'm not sure. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah! Well, I did derive that formula as part of the exercise, and the principal value does define an analytic function in both $\alpha$ and $t$. All the principal value is is the arithmetic mean of two convergent integrals, so at first thought I can't quite see the problem. Differentiating the interior and exterior convergent integrals yields valid formulae, their means yields a sensible principal value; is the problem that the resulting p.v. isn't necessarily the same as the p.v. of the derivative of the original integral?

Comment: @FShrike  Yes.  In some situations it might be the case that $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,a) \, \mathrm dx \ne\operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial }{\partial a}f(x,a) \, \mathrm dx. $$  I think G.H. Hardy wrote a paper about when it can be justified, but I've not been able to find it.

Comment: I see that Hardy also wrote a paper on when: $$\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,a)\,\mathrm{d}x$$Is a continuous function in $a$. Blagouchine assumes this throughout the paper, and uses it to calculate principal values as in: $$\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sinh x\pm\sinh t}\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{\alpha\to0}\left\{\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-i\alpha x}}{\sinh x\pm\sinh t}\,\mathrm{d}x\right\}$$And I myself have used this many times to complete his exercises. Do you happen to know about the validity of this?

Comment: I'd have thought that the dominated convergence theorem would be sufficient, since the $P.V.$ is the mean of convergent integrals, but I ask just in case it's deeper than that (and I cannot access the paper)

Comment: @FShrike   Basically we can differentiate under the integral sign if $\left| \frac{\partial }{\partial a} f(x,a) \right| \le g(x) \, $ for all $a$ , and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \, \mathrm dx$ converges.  I don't know if this can be extended to Cauchy principal value integrals.

Comment: And for the continuity?

Comment: @FShrike  It sounds reasonable, but I just don't know how these theorems extend to Cauchy principal value integrals.

Comment: I was in email conversation with Blagouchine himself, and came by all four of Hardy's essays. The relevant one about differentiation may be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psUTXh1rvusoBA2c8kTuC9oCDyCpW9OL/view?usp=sharing), and I will share the other three if you so wish as you have been so helpful to me!